# What is the correct way to load web font in a polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, webfonts, web-component

I've created a little polymer element to mimic a 7segment display, the element need to load the font fontlibrary.org/face/segment7.

Where and how is the correct way to load it for the element ?

At first, I put:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/segment7"/>
```

in the element. This was not working in firefox (but it was in chrome) so I searched more and found www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules so I modified the element to reflect that and modified my code to:

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="font-segment7.html">
```

and created a font-segment.html file:

```
<dom-module id="font-segment7">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/segment7"/>
</dom-module>
```

The result is the same, working in chrome, not in firefox (no error and the font-segment.html file is downloaded), so, I'm wondering if this kind of indirection is designed for that, I feel it's more for shared style and not for one shot.

The demo for the element is here https://potens1.gitlab.io/seven-segment-element/components/seven-segment-element/ and the code repository is there https://gitlab.com/potens1/seven-segment-element

Is this the way to work with webcomponents (polymer?), or should the font be embedded in the component ?

Thank you.

PS: sorry, not enough reputation to post links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define the correct way to include a font as the way the Polymer Project does it: [font-roboto](https://github.com/Polymer/font-roboto)

The "element" consists of just a `<style>` tag.

For you this would look like this (`font-segment7.html`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fontlibrary.org/face/segment7"/>
```

This works for me in Firefox with your `seven-segment-element`.

**Note:** The fontlibrary provides the segment7 font as .otf ([OpenType](http://caniuse.com/#search=otf)) which is only partially supported in IE.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, for the ff thing, I don't understand why the 'type="text/css" ' is blocking. For the main question,  the difference is font-roboto is used by a lot of paper elements, font-segment7 will not be reused (or very few, I guess). I found it to be a lot of boiler plate without any benefit and that's why I wonder about good usage. It sound a bit strange to me the font-roboto does not follow what's explain in [doc](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules) (no dom-module).

Comment: Well, a `dom-module` is used to construct an element. A font include is not really an element since you want to use the font in the element you are including it and not using the font as an element with it's own content. You could compare a font to a mixin (such as [iron-flex-layout](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout/blob/master/iron-flex-layout.html)) which also "doesn't follow what's explained in doc"